# Can apps created with View-Based table view in Xcode 4.2 run on OS X 10.5-10.6?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, osx-lion

WWDC 2011 and OS X Lion introduced View-Based table view for building interfaces. However, can applications created with these new tools run on Tiger and Snow Leopard? Or would we have to resort back to cell-based table views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The class `NSTableRowView` is available only in Lion or better. You'd have to use a cell-based table for backwards compatibility.

[Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Got it. Why is that though? View-based table seems like a build/compile time technology that simply affects how the application is written, but not how it is run. Is this true?

Comment: Not quite sure what that means... but NSTableView resides within AppKit, which is a system framework. The code simply didn't exist in the system prior to 10.7.

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible to package the NSTableRowView into the application itself so that it can be run on earlier platforms?

Comment: @Tony: No, you cannot package system frameworks into your application.